# Perform 3 operations on stack

Tags: algorithm

I am given an empty stack , I need to support three operations :

```
PUSH x : Push element x onto the stack
POP :  Pop the top element
INC L R x : Increment the L to R elements by x
```

After each query I need to tell the top element of array. How to do this question if their can be 10^6 queries.

We can't update all the elements again and again. So please provide an efficient solution.

Comment: "Please do my homework, and efficiently while you're at it"

Comment: @tux3 It seems homework ?

Comment: @tux3 My bad !! But its not

Comment: Really ? Sorry then. What exactly do you need this for if I may ask ? I'm curious now.

Comment: What does "Increment the lower d elements by x" mean? Can you post an example?

Comment: @IVlad Assume you are given a range L,R and you need to increment in that range by x

Answer (score 1):

We can use a [segment tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/) that supports your required operations in `O(log n)`:

1. **Increment all elements in a given range**

For each node in your segment tree associated with an interval included in your given range, increment a counter `num_increments` for it: this counter will tell you how many times the elements in this range were all incremented. Only do this for the topmost such nodes, do not recursively go down to their children once you've done this.

2. **Query the value at a given index**

The answer to this is `v[index] + number_of_increments`. You can find the number of increments by finding the node associated with the index in the segment tree and keeping track of its parents' `num_increments` values as you walk down to it.

There are a couple of things to consider, depending on your exact problem:

1. For a given `L, R`, maybe set `R = min(R, stack.Size)`, as it makes no sense to increment elements not yet in the stack. Or maybe it does for your problem, I don't know. If it does make sense for your problem, it makes things easier, and it invalidates my second point below;
2. What happens when you pop an element from the stack? This method will still mark its position as incremented, so if you push one back, it will consider it incremented by 1. Think about how you can also support decrement for a given index (it's similar to the query operation).

Incrementation by `x` instead of `1` should be easy to achieve.

Comment: What's the complexity of constructing this tree before usage?

Comment: @ShellFish - O(n) because there are no increments initially: just declare an array big enough to hold the tree.

Comment: Is the log(n) cost a one time cost or per operation/query? If the former is true, then this is a nice solution!

Comment: @ShellFish - no, it's per query / operation. You have to do it for each query, resulting in `O(queries * log n)` performance.

Comment: Plus O(n) for construction, no? So once you have n/log(n) queries this solution is slower than the other one.

Comment: @ShellFish - it's slower than `O(n + queries)` in total, yes. That would mean `O(1)` per query.

Comment: Well kuddos then, nice answer, +1

Answer (score 0):

There will be more push than pop operations, otherwise the stack would be empty in the end. Look for the last push that doesn't have a corresponding pop, this is the element that will be on top of the stack in the end. Now simply increment this element for each appropriate inc operation.

Complexity for this method:

O(2n) computation

O(queries) memory

n = total number of operations of all queries

Comment: You're given more than one query.

Comment: Supply an example in which this method fails. Multiple queries can be "pasted" together, no?

Comment: I don't think it fails, I think it's not necessarily efficient as written. How do you "increment this element for each appropriate inc operation"?

Comment: Keep track of it's position in the stack, for every following inc check if ťhe operation applies. This requires O(n) work. You may find a more efficient solution but not asymptotically.

Comment: I don't see how that helps. You have to increment a range. Consider a hundred increments of the form `[1, 100]; [2, 100]; ...` and you'll only reach a query for element 60 much later. How will you know how many times 60 was incremented?

Comment: I don't see see the problem. You have an index at every inc, if the index is within bounds you increase. After a few pops and pushes you adept the index, then you repeat the process.

Comment: You have a **range** at every inc. How do you efficiently increment all the numbers in that range?

Comment: You don't, he only needs the top element in the end so discard the rest.

Comment: But he has more queries, so the top element can change. The top element can be the 100th element for one query and the 60th for another, so you can't discard anything.

Comment: You can easily find all elements that will be on top after each query. Do the same thing for all these elements rather than one.

Comment: Starting a backward search from each query end, you can find all these elements in O(n) work.

Comment: Yes, and that is `O(n)` **per query**, which is the brute force method.

Comment: It is not brute force, in this case n is the total number of operations of all queries.

Comment: I don't understand how you can claim pure `O(n)` for all queries. Surely you must at least sort the queries or something to get to that? And you must answer every query, so it has to at least be `O(n + num_queries)`.

Comment: Why? I do assume the queries sequential not concurrent. Am I wrong about this assumption?

Comment: " n is the total number of operations of all queries." note that I assumed that `n = maximum size the stack can get to`. If we take `n` to be what I assumed, then you algorithm is `O(n^2)`, because the total number of operations of all queries can be `O(n^2)` if they are all `inc 0 n, inc 1, n, inc 2, n, ...`.